# Wordpress missing "/" after domain name

Tags: wordpress, url

I'm having issue on my wordpress site, after I migrate, some of my image source links are broken

Example:
[www.example.comwp-content/uploads/test.png](http://www.example.comwp-content/uploads/test.png) -> this is what I got

[www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/test.png](http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/test.png) -> this should be the correct source links

Appreciate your help thanks

Comment: Backup your database & replace "www.example.comwp-content/" this to "www.example.com/wp-content/" and import database again.

Comment: Did you use a search and replace plugin? - If so, you might have had the trailingslash in one of the fields.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try several things.

You can try and 'check' if the URL's are correct in your database by making a small change to your `wp-config.php` file. You can use

```php
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
```

and

```php
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursiteurl.com' );
```

To change the URL used in you installation. If these solve the problem, then you know it's in the Database. The next step is to change those values in your database. What you are looking for is the `wp-options` table and within, the row `home` and the row `siteurl` (in the `option_name` column). They should be row 1 and 2 of that table.

If the edit in `wp-config.php` didn't help or solve you problem, then it might be a rule your `.htaccess` file.
Simplest fix is to empty/delete that `.htaccess` file while having the Permalinks options page open. After deletion, save the Permalinks page. That should reset your `.htaccess` file to defaults. Else you can find here more information about the default configuration: [WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/)

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```